# How to test App update in UWP app?

Tags: uwp, windows-10

We have an UWP app on the store and generated a new build and uploaded it, but many users complain that the app got many problems after the update.

How can I update the App in my phone to see how it works? Mainly, i want to test that old data is still accessible after the update.

Thanks,

Comment: You can use [WinAppDeployCmd tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Mt203806.aspx) to update the app that is already installed with this command `WinAppDeployCmd update -file`.

Answer (score 1):

If your both apps (old and new one) have the same ApplicationIds, then if you install old app and afterwards install new version without uninstalling the old, then it should simulate the 'update' process - old data should persist.

Though the best thing would be to publish a beta version in the store under different name, then update it with new beta and check how it behaves. Note that beta updates usually are certified much faster (can take few hours).

Answer (score 1):

Usually problems occurred because of legacy app settings. New version of the app may incorrectly read old settings.

You can check settings manually. Install old app and copy settings from it somewhere. App settings located in:

```
C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Packages\{full_package_name}\LocalState
```

Then install the new app. If you run it from VS, it will wipe all the old settings. But we saved it, so not a big deal. Close the app, put saved "old" settings back to app's folder and run the app again. Now you can debug the app behavior with an the old settings.

Just note that this folder is hidden and it sometimes not easy to access it. But I had not problems accessing it from Total Commander.

Comment: Excellent idea, I didn't think about it!